# getting instance of generic subclasses using its reference

Tags: java, generic-programming

Ignore this question

I have a subclass which extends generic super class. Here it is

```
BlueColorPainter extends ColorPainter<BlueColor>;
GreenColorPainter extends ColorPainter<GreenColor>;
RedColorPainter extends ColorPainter<RedColor>;
```

ColorPainter painter is an abstarct class which has unimplemented method paint().

I have declared enum with

```
class enum ColorsUsage{
    BLUE("blue","BlueColorPainter","BlueColor"),
    Green("green","GrerenColorPainter","GreenColor"),
    Red("red","RedColorPainter","RedColor");

    String colorName,colorPainterClass,colorClass;
    ColorPainters(String colorName, String colorPainterClass,String colorClass) {
        this.colorName = colorName;
        this.colorPainterClass = colorPainterClass;
        this.colorClass = colorClass;
    }
}
```

When color name is passed,the method should return the appropriate colorPainter Instance.
like

String color="any"; //xxx can be blue,red,green

```
ColorPainter<?> colorPainter;
if(color=="blue")   
colorPainter=new BlueColorPainter();
else if(color=="red")   
colorPainter=new RedColorPainter();
if(color=="green")   
colorPainter=new GreenColorPainter();
```

I want an implementation method which is equivalent to  above if else condition.

I have written some code making use of Enum class ColorsUsage. But could not complete it.

```
public static ? getPainter(String color){
       for(ColorsUsage cp:ColorsUsage.values()){
         //write code to create the instance of painter class, ex:BlueColorPainter 
       }
    }
```

please fill the "?" and the commented line.

how to call that method.

```
ColorPainter<?> painter= getPainter("blue");
```

Comment: `class enum...` that doesnt compile or make sense

Comment: edited the enum class please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static ? getPainter(String color){
   for(ColorsUsage cp:ColorsUsage.values()){
     //write code to create the instance of painter class, ex:BlueColorPainter 
   }
 }
```

In above method; instead of using Generics you can return Object (i.e. super class) and then using `instanceof` keyword you can find the exact type of the instance in the calling method.

Comment: public static Object getPainter(String color){
   for(ColorsUsage cp:ColorsUsage.values()){
     return Class.forName(cp.colorPainterClass);
   }
 }

[b]calling the above method[b]
ColorPainter painter= getPainter("blue");

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't understand the intention of generics.
Additionally you make it too complicated.

Try this, but keep in mind to add modifiers like `public` or `private`:

```
class ColorPainters{

  static ColorPainters BLUE = new ColorPainters("blue","BlueColorPainter","BlueColor"),
                       GREEN = new ColorPainters("green","GreenColorPainter","GreenColor"),
                       RED = new ColorPainters("red","RedColorPainter","RedColor");

  String colorName, colorPainterClass, colorClass;

  public ColorPainters(String name,String painter,String color){
      this.colorName=name;
      this.colorPainterClass= painter;
      this.colorClass=color;
 }  

  public static ColorPainters getPainter(String color){
      if(color.equals(BLUE.colorName))
          return BLUE;
      else if(color.equals(GREEN.colorName))
          return GREEN;
      else if(color.equals(RED.colorName))
          return RED;
      else
          return new ColorPainters(color, color + "ColorPainter", color + "Color");
  } 
}
```

Comment: It is not that i dont know generics.You probably didn't get my question. I am not asking how to implement the generic class.The colorPainterClass and colorClass in the enums shoudd be used to create instance using reflection. I dont want if/else statment to instantiate the painter class. method is Like factory method pattern.

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure that I don't understand what you want. You either try to explain your problem in a different way or you wait for others to help you. I'm still too dumb to understand you...

Comment: lasercats sry the enum class name is ColorsUsage not ColorPainter

Comment: can you make your example compilable? `enum class` confuses me as well as it confuses other people.